# Laravel logout route in Vue component

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

In my Laravel 5.5 project I have a Vue component as a separate file with .vue extension.
In its template there is a vue-router link. Also, I need to place the standard Laravel logout link here.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><router-link to="/">Home</router-link></li>
            <!-- place where I want to add Laravel logout link -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have tried to insert the Laravel logout link like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><router-link to="/">Home</router-link></li>

          <li>
            <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();    
                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                 Logout
            </a>
            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
          </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

But the code does not compile in this case. I see I can't use Laravel routes in Vue component. What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can define a method to call logout route**

*you can't use laravel blade syntax inside vue component*

```
<template>
  <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><router-link to="/">Home</router-link></li>

          <li><a href="#" @click.prevent="logout">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
             csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
             }),   
        methods:{
            logout:function(){
               axios.post('logout').then(response => {
                  if (response.status === 302 || 401) {
                    console.log('logout')
                  }
                  else {
                    // throw error and go to catch block
                  }
                }).catch(error => {

              });
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

note:

- here i used [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for http requests, if you have no idea about that then you can also use normal ajax request
- for csrf token you should include csrf data in your meta tag.

Comment: If you get an error associated with the route and method "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE." then make sure to use axios.post('/logout')... mind the "/" part.

Comment: you don't pass csrf field

Answer (score 3):

Well, Laravel adds csrf token automatically in axios request. So this code is working for me

```
<template>

    <span>
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="logout()">Logout</a>
    </span>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Logout",
        methods: {
            logout() {
                axios.post('/logout')
                    .catch(error => {
                       window.location.href = '/login';
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```